# Is there a library to perform reflection on .Net objects based on a string?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm looking for a library that would allow you to perform reflection on an object using a string, e.g.

```cs
class SampleClass {
    public SampleClass Child {get; set;}
    public string SomeValue {get;set;}
}
var a = new SampleClass { Child = new SampleClass { SomeValue = "v"}};
var parser = new ReflectionParser();
var result = parser.Parse("Child.SomeValue", a);
// result is "v"
```

If not, I'm considering writing one and open sourcing it - but I didn't want to re-invent the wheel. Initially it would just get property values, but in the longer term I could see it gaining the ability to running methods, parsing arguments as need be.

The closest I have found is an XPath style library https://code.google.com/archive/p/antix-software/wikis/AntixReflectionQuery.wiki referenced in [Using an XPath-style Query with Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324432/using-an-xpath-style-query-with-reflection) and [Traversing an arbitrary C# object graph using XPath/applying XSL transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371807/traversing-an-arbitrary-c-sharp-object-graph-using-xpath-applying-xsl-transforms) - however this doesn't appear to be available any more.

Comment: Good question! Since this syntax (`Child.SomeValue`) is used by various data binding features (e.g. WPF data binding), you might even find something in the BCL itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET base class library contains a [`DataBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.databinder) class which does exactly what you want.

It was designed for ASP.NET WebForms databinding, so it's in the `System.Web.UI` namespace and requires a reference to `System.Web`. But don't let that stop you, it can be used outside of web projects just as well.

```
class SampleClass
{
    public SampleClass Child { get; set; }
    public SampleClass[] Children { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}

var a = new SampleClass { Child = new SampleClass { SomeValue = "v" } };

var result = DataBinder.Eval(a, "Child.SomeValue");
Console.WriteLine(result); // yields v
```

DataBinder also supports indexing over collections, so `Children[0].SomeValue` would also be evaluated correctly:

```
var a = new SampleClass { Children = new SampleClass[] { new SampleClass { SomeValue = "v" } } };

var result = DataBinder.Eval(a, "Children[0].SomeValue");
Console.WriteLine(result); // yields v
```

Comment: I would try to use `nameof` when available. `int index = 0; $"{nameof(SampleClass.Children)}[{index}].{nameof(SampleClass.SomeValue)}"` => `"Children[0].SomeValue"`

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I had some ideas in the longer term of allowing function evaluation too - e.g. SomeObject.GetResultsBefore('2017-05-01') but this is a great start for now and I'm not sure that'll be needed.